# why does my while loop not stop when I type stop?

Tags: c++

I have a while loop in c++ like

```
bool stopped = false;
while (!stopped) {
  string input;
  cin >> input;
  if (input == "stop") {
    stopped = true;
  }
}
```

and it isn't stopping where it just has a blank line when I use the stop

my full code is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  bool stopped = false;
  ofstream script;
  string scriptname;
  getline(cin >> ws, scriptname);
  script.open(scriptname);
  while (!stopped) {
    string input;
    cin >> input;
    if (input == "line") {
      string lineInput;
      getline(cin >> ws, lineInput);
      int i = lineInput.find(',');
      lineInput[i] = ':';
      script << lineInput << endl;
    } else if(input == "wait") {
      string waitInput;
      getline(cin >> ws, waitInput);
      if (!(waitInput.find(',') != string::npos)) {
        script << "***" << endl;
      } else {
        script << "***" << waitInput << endl;
      }
    } else if(input == "action") {
      string actionInput;
      getline(cin >> ws, actionInput);
      int i = actionInput.find(',');
      actionInput += ')';
      actionInput.insert((i + 2), 1, '(');
      script << actionInput << endl;
    } else if(input == "stop") {
      stopped = true;
    }
  }
  script.close();
  return 0;
}
```

I am using the input where I first enter "test" then hit enter, then after that I type "stop" and hit enter, it generates the file but after I use the stop part it just has a blank line.

it turns out that it was just because the atom package I was using to run it doesn't stop it for some reason, I tried using konsole instead of just atom and it worked

Comment: I am using some more that adds some text to a file where one thing replaces a comma with a colon, another adds some asterisks to text , and another adds some parentheses around a part of text, and they all add it to a file, but they all work.

Comment: Without seeing your real code and a sample of the input you're using that isn't working it's hard to guess at what might be the problem. Consider a [mcve].

Comment: *"after I use the stop part it just has a blank line"* - What are you expecting? And where is the blank line?

Comment: After typing in the word "test" which is the name of the file, you then type in the word "stop" which causes the program to end. When are you expecting anything else to happen?

Comment: when I use the other things it has the same blank line, so to try to find the issue I used just the stop, and for me it isn't ending the program, but is just how it looks like if I use one of the other inputs

Comment: If I enter "test" then "stop" the program exits for me. Consider adding some output to key areas so you can see what's happening or use a debugger to examine the contents of the variables when it isn't working for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since this code stops when I enter `stop` (I'd suggest trying it locally to confirm), there must be a problem in the code you *haven't* shown us.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    bool stopped = false;
    while (!stopped) {
        std::string input;
        std::cin >> input;
        if (input == "stop") {
            stopped = true;
        }
        // some more code here?
    }
}
```

I'd be guessing that the loop *is* stopping but that other code you have is still doing something to the output file you mentioned in one of your comments. For example, if you have some code where my `// some more code here?` comment is, it will execute even if you've entered `stop`. The actual loop won't exit until it goes back to the `while` bit.

Until we see the real code, there's not much else we can do.

---

And, now that you've added your full code, I'm pretty confident the problem doesn't lie with the code. Running that exact code on my system gives:

```
pax:~> g++ --std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -o prog prog.cpp && ./prog
test
stop
pax:~> wc test
0 0 0 test
```

It exits on `stop` and the resultant file contains nothing, as expected.

Now it *may* be an environmental problem caused by the way you're running it. I know that running stuff within Visual Studio will sometimes leave the window open for you but it at least prints something to inform you of that:

```
C:\Users\Pax\ConsoleApp1.exe (process 5400) exited with code 0.      Press any key to close this window . . .
```

If you *are* running it from an IDE, I would run it from a proper shell (`cmd.exe` or a terminal) just to check if this is the case.

---

As an aside, I have modified your code a little so you know what it's doing at each point (with prompts rather than just a blank line with cursor):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    bool stopped = false;
    ofstream script;
    string scriptname;
    cout << "scriptname: ";
    getline(cin >> ws, scriptname);
    script.open(scriptname);
    while (!stopped) {
        string input;
        cout << "input: ";
        cin >> input;
        if (input == "line") {
            string lineInput;
            cout << "lineInput: ";
            getline(cin >> ws, lineInput);
            int i = lineInput.find(',');
            lineInput[i] = ':';
            script << lineInput << endl;
        } else if(input == "wait") {
            string waitInput;
            cout << "waitInput: ";
            getline(cin >> ws, waitInput);
            if (!(waitInput.find(',') != string::npos)) {
                script << "***" << endl;
            } else {
                script << "***" << waitInput << endl;
            }
        } else if(input == "action") {
            string actionInput;
            cout << "actionInput: ";
            getline(cin >> ws, actionInput);
            int i = actionInput.find(',');
            actionInput += ')';
            actionInput.insert((i + 2), 1, '(');
            script << actionInput << endl;
        } else if(input == "stop") {
            stopped = true;
        }
    }
    script.close();
    cout << "EXIT\n";
    return 0;
}
```

That appears to work just fine with everything being written to the file. However, there *is* at least *one* small coding error (in multiple paces):

```cpp
int i = lineInput.find(',');
lineInput[i] = ':';
```

If you enter a line with no commas, `i` will be set to `std::npos`, which is `-1` (or the unsigned equivalent). If you then use that as an index in the second line above, it'll either change a character a *long* way past the end of the string or the character before the start of the string. Both those cases are undefined behaviour (which is why I haven't spent much time researching it).

You should probably have protection similar to the condition found in the `wait` case:

```cpp
int i = lineInput.find(',');
if (i != std::npos) {
    lineInput[i] = ':';
}
```

You'll also need something similar in the `action` case as well (for the `insert` call), and I'd get rid of the double-negative in `wait`:

```cpp
// if (!(waitInput.find(',') != string::npos)) {
// Instead, you <humour> shouldn't not </humour> do it this way:
if (waitInput.find(',') == string::npos) {
    script << "***" << endl;
} else {
    script << "***" << waitInput << endl;
}
```

Comment: This feels more like a comment than an answer to be honest.

Comment: I added the full code, and the input I used.

Comment: @Galik: for a start, it has enough detail that it wont *fit* in a comment. Secondly (though this no doubt post-dates your comment), I've added extra stuff to hopefully guide OP where to look.